# How to assign a user to a hotel when inviting a user with devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, devise-invitable

I'm trying to assign a user to a hotel when inviting them with the devise_invitable gem.

In my app the admin can invite users. The invite url seems to be ok, but the user that is invited gets access to **all hotels** of an admin instead of the **current hotel** an admin is inviting them from.

url invitations that is being sent (hotel.id = 109)

```
http://localhost:3000/users/invitation/new.109
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :hotels do
    resources :users
end
```

models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hotels, through: :user_hotels
  enum role: [:owner, :admin, :employee, :accountant]
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :invitable
end

class UserHotel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hotels, through: :user_hotels
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @user = User.new
    @user.hotel = @hotel
    authorize @user
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @user.hotel = @hotel
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to hotel_users_path(@hotel), notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :role, :hotel_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you setup the devise controllers??? you also need not nest the user inside hotels in your routes

Comment: please refer https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers and configure your devise controller so it will become much flexible for your needs

Comment: You're basically just duplicating the entire functionality of devise_invitable here - and there are a lot of parts missing. If you want to use the gem then create a subclass of Devise::InvitationsController and add your additional logic there.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I generated the devise controllers and subsequently tried to generate the invitations controller by inserting ```rails generate devise:controllers users -c=invitations ```. However I get the error message ```Running via Spring preloader in process 64830
Could not find "invitations_controller.rb" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
/Users/name/code/name/app/lib/templates/devise/controllers
/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.0/lib/generators/templates/controllers
 ```

Comment: You don't need to generate the controller through devise. Just setup a controller that inherits from Devise::InvitationsController. You can probaly get by with just creating a create method and calling super with a block that saves a reference to the hotel on the user model.